# How to determine current SELinux context within a script

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to get an existing application running under SELinux which is causing endless pain. Matters would be eased somewhat if I knew what contexts the various components were running in - users have contexts, files have contexts but it seems that a process can also have a context which is only loosely related to the user and file (by an arbitrary set of rules in the policy).

Making some sense of the morass wold be facilitated if I knew what context a process was executing in - is there a command providing this as part of a standard installation?

I could look for the current process id in the output of `ps auxZ`, but these seems a somewhat ugly solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `id -Z` or `getpidcon $$`